# How to limit the number of selected check-boxes in React JS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I want to limit the maximum number of checked check-boxes to be 3. At the same time I also want to create an array of the selected values. Please note that, I am using [Ant design's checkbox](https://ant.design/components/checkbox/). Code is as given in [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/185l1l6nl4).

```
handleCheckbox = (e) => {
    let qlen = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
    if(qlen < 3) {
    if(e.target.checked) {
      this.setState({
        indstryValue: this.state.indstryValue.concat([e.target.value])
      });
    } else {
      var arr = this.state.indstryValue;
      arr = arr.filter(item => item !== e.target.value);
      this.setState({
        indstryValue: arr
      });
    }
  }

  var checks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]');
  var max = 2;
  for (var i = 0; i < checks.length; i++)
    checks[i].onclick = selectiveCheck;
  function selectiveCheck(event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    var checkedChecks = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    if (checkedChecks.length >= max + 1)
      return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don’t see any React code? In vanilla js you can store the checked boxes references in an array. When a fourth box is added, remove the first one, and use the stored reference to uncheck that box

Comment: @Kokodoko Please check the codesandbox.io code. Here I only posted relevant method. `Hello.js` is main file.

Comment: I suggest reading a bit more about React databinding and conditional rendering to keep track of which checkboxes are checked, instead of `document.querySelectorAll`. React can couple your array to the checkboxes automatically. Setting the array value to false will disable the checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of react `state` to do this. The following example conditionally disables checkboxes when two are checked. [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4j79z0vv7w)

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Checkbox, Row, Col } from "antd";

class CheckBoxed extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      checked: []
    };
  }
  onChange = checkedValues => {
    this.setState(() => {
      return { checked: checkedValues };
    });
  };

  isDisabled = id => {
    return (
      this.state.checked.length > 1 && this.state.checked.indexOf(id) === -1
    );
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Checkbox.Group style={{ width: "100%" }} onChange={this.onChange}>
        <Row>
          <Col span={8}>
            <Checkbox value="A" disabled={this.isDisabled("A")}>
              A
            </Checkbox>
          </Col>
          <Col span={8}>
            <Checkbox value="B" disabled={this.isDisabled("B")}>
              B
            </Checkbox>
          </Col>
          <Col span={8}>
            <Checkbox value="C" disabled={this.isDisabled("C")}>
              C
            </Checkbox>
          </Col>
          <Col span={8}>
            <Checkbox value="D" disabled={this.isDisabled("D")}>
              D
            </Checkbox>
          </Col>
          <Col span={8}>
            <Checkbox value="E" disabled={this.isDisabled("E")}>
              E
            </Checkbox>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Checkbox.Group>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CheckBoxed />, document.getElementById("container"));
```